# $t^2=at+b$ where $t$ is real and $a,b$ are +ve integers. Show that $t^3$ is not equal to $8t+5$.

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

> $t^2=at+b$ where $t$ is real and $a,b$ are +ve integers. Show that $t^3$ is not equal to  $8t+5$.

After  solving for $t$ in terms of $a, b$ could not  advance any further.

Comment: do you mean positive?

Comment: $t$ is real and $a, b$ are positive integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$t^3 = t(t^2) = t(at+b) = at^2 + bt = a(at+b) + bt = (a^2 +b)t + ab.$$  Now all that remains is to show that the system $$a^2 + b = 8, \\ ab = 5,$$ has no positive integer solutions.  Clearly, $ab = 5$ implies $\{a, b\} = \{1, 5\}$ in some order.  So you have only two cases to check.

Comment: Even with negative integers, there are in total four cases to check.

Comment: yup, that's easy, got it. Thanks!